# Pre determined x and y values of the tree layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a simple tree layout example, I want to have the source & target nodes to be set values

data is like so:

```
   var Data = {"name" : "A", "info" : "tst", "childrens" : [
      {"name" : "A1", x:100, y:100 },
      {"name" : "A2", x:50, y:400 },
      {"name" : "A3", x:50, y:100 },
      {"name" : "A311", x:350, y:120 },
      {"name" : "A312", x:250, y:170 },
      {"name" : "A312", x:175, y:200 }

    ]};
```

As you can see I have defined x & y values to each node to position them where I'd like.

However, it seems has no affect on the layout whatsoever.

I have attempted to change the projection to:

```
            translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"
```

Also I tried to change the node variable, but it seems to have the same affect as if I changed it on the projection.

I am wondering whether it is possible to set positions using treelayout and it isnt allowed.

Also, instead of using svg:circle I wish to use svg.symbol:

```
   node.append("path")
       .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(circle))
       .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
```

However, instead it shows nothing but the lines, without the text - dont understand why.

So essentially I tried to position the children & the root where I choose.

Any help  OR advice would be greatly appreicated.  http://jsfiddle.net/3twUr/2/

EDIT:

var line = d3.svg.diagonal().data(data).enter()

```
    .source({x: d.x, y: d.y})
    .target({x: d.x, y: d.y});

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("d", line);

     var pos = [{source: "A" ,target: 'A1'},
                {source: "A" , target: 'A2'} ];
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the tree layout (and most other layouts) is that it determines the positions of the nodes for you. What you are trying to do is entirely unsupported.

Given that you have node positions already, it sounds like it would be much easier simply to place the symbols and lines where you want them to be. That is, something like

```
svg.selectAll("circle").data(Data.childrens)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
```

Similarly for the links, which you would need to calculate yourself. It sounds like you want to link the parent nodes to their children, so this would be relatively straightforward.

This approach also has the advantage that you're free to use any node/link style you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Is it not possible to use the svg.Diagonal to calculate the distance between the nodes for the links?

Comment: The line generators are only used to connect given points. So it would be enough to give basically two points to `d3.svg.diagonal()`, but you would have to choose those two points, i.e. create a set of two points for every link you want to have.

Comment: Following my edit is there a way that I could map my objects so it gets its source/positioning through my data?

Comment: It looks like in your original data you have positions only for the children -- you would need to calculate the positions for every node you want to display before you could do that.